# Pytorch uint8 tensor indexing

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to slice signal_matrix by in_inds, but uint8 indexing is a different i guess. Can someone explain how it suppose to work?

```
signal_matrix = torch.tensor(
                       [[0, 0, 1, 1],
                        [0, 0, 0, 0],
                        [0, 0, 1, 1],
                        [0, 1, 1, 0],
                        [1, 0, 1, 0],
                        [0, 0, 0, 0],
                        [0, 0, 0, 0],
                        [0, 0, 0, 0],
                        [0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=torch.uint8)

in_inds = torch.tensor(
         [[ 0,  2,  3],                     
          [ 1,  2,  4],
          [ 0,  0,  0]][::-1], dtype= torch.uint8
          )

out_inds = torch.tensor(
         [ 5, 6, 7], dtype= torch.uint8)

op_inds = torch.tensor(
        [ [1, 1, 1, 1],                    
          [0, 0, 0, 0],
          [2, 2, 2, 2]], dtype= torch.uint8)

in_signals = signal_matrix[in_inds]
```

`IndexError: The shape of the mask [3, 3] at index 0 does not match the shape of the indexed tensor [9, 4] at index 0`

In general, I expected something like this. And the same result is obtained with int32.

```
tensor([[[0, 0, 1, 1],
         [0, 0, 1, 1],
         [0, 0, 1, 1]],

        [[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 1],
         [1, 0, 1, 0]],

        [[0, 0, 1, 1],
         [0, 0, 1, 1],
         [0, 1, 1, 0]]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the deal:

When using `uint8` as an index, it's interpreted as *masking* instead of indexing. That is, you'll get a new tensor containing the values of the previous tensor at those locations in which your mask has positive values.

Note that using `uint8` for indexing (which is actually masking) is deprecated and should not be done.

Concretely:

```
data = torch.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))

# tensor([[0, 1, 2],
#         [3, 4, 5],
#         [6, 7, 8]])

in_inds = torch.tensor(
         [[ 0,  2,  3],                     
          [ 1,  2,  4],
          [ 0,  0,  0]][::-1], dtype= torch.uint8)
          
torch.allclose(data[in_inds], data[in_inds > 0]) # True
# tensor([3, 4, 5, 7, 8])
```

On the other hand, you can perform actual indexing by using a `int` or a 'long' tensor as an index:

```
data[0] # tensor([0, 1, 2])
data[2] # tensor([6, 7, 8])
data[torch.tensor([2, 2, 0], dtype=torch.int)]
# tensor([[6, 7, 8],
#         [6, 7, 8],
#         [0, 1, 2]])
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider voting for the answer in addition to accepting it in case you found it useful